# Mapping jsp for a url in Spring 3 without using controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, java-ee-6

How to map a jsp for a url in spring 3 without requestmapping to any controller.

eg. /login to login.jsp without having any userdefined controller in between

Like URLFILENAMECONTROLLER in spring2.5, similarly in spring 3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/login" view-name="login"/>
```

Assuming that you have defined a ViewResolver, something like this:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

This will resolve a request to `/login` to a `/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp` page

Answer (score 10):

You can use [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller) paragraph from Spring docs for reference. In short, you can do in several ways one of them with `view-controller` annotation. The other way when using `Java Config`:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
  }

}
```

Where the code maps request for `/login` to `/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp` view if the view resolver is defined as in the previous answer.